# How to use QtGui in PyQt4 to collect input variables to a python program?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtgui

Instead of input flags on the command line, using sys.argv, I want to change my python program so that a GUI with dialog boxes lets users provide answers to some questions. After the "apply" button is pushed I want the dialog GUI to dissapear and then the code to run normally with the variables provided in dialog boxes. I have tried many different ways using QtGui. Either it crashes, or, the answers are not known for the main program. Below I show one of my many attempts. In this example the answer is not known after the apply button is pressed. The output is

```
after widget answer1 = <blank no matter what I write in the dialog box>
```

I would very much appreciate help on how to change this code so that the variable "a1" is filled with the string given in the dialog box.
Thank you!

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()

        self.answer1 = QtGui.QLabel()
        q1Edit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        q1Edit.textChanged[str].connect(self.q1Changed)

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(20)

        grid.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Question 1'), 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(q1Edit, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(self.answer1, 1, 2)

        applyBtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Apply', self)
        applyBtn.clicked.connect(self.close)

        self.answer1Text = self.answer1.text()

        grid.addWidget(applyBtn,4,3)

        self.setLayout(grid)     

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)
        self.show()


    def q1Changed(self, text):
        self.answer1.setText(text)

    def returnAnswer1(self):
        return self.answer1Text


def main():    
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget() 
    a1 = w.returnAnswer1()
    print("after widget answer1 = " + a1)    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks to JRazor, this was in the end the solution:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Widget(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.answer1 = QtGui.QLabel()
        q1Edit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        q1Edit.textChanged.connect(self.q1Changed)

        self.answer2 = QtGui.QLabel()
        q2Edit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        q2Edit.textChanged.connect(self.q2Changed)

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(20)

        grid.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Question 1'), 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(q1Edit, 1, 1)

        grid.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('Question 2'), 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(q2Edit, 2, 1)

        applyBtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Apply', self)
        applyBtn.clicked.connect(self.close)

        grid.addWidget(applyBtn,3,2)
        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 350, 300)

    def q1Changed(self, text):
        self.answer1.setText(text)

    def q2Changed(self, text):
        self.answer2.setText(text)

    def returnAnswer1(self):
        return self.answer1.text()

    def returnAnswer2(self):
        return self.answer2.text()

    @staticmethod
    def getData(parent=None):
        dialog = Widget(parent)
        dialog.exec_()
        return [dialog.returnAnswer1(), dialog.returnAnswer2()]

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = Widget()
    data = window.getData()
    print data[0]
    print data[1]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need change `QWidget` to `QDialog`:

```
class Widget(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)
```

Then create a function for `class Widget` with a static method. Function will get parent to dialog window and return text from edit field:

```
@staticmethod
def getData(parent = None):
    dialog = Widget(parent)
    dialog.exec_()
    return dialog.returnAnswer1()
```

Then call the window with passing a value:

```
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    window = Widget()
    print window.getData()  # window is value from edit field
```

Also, you need delete `self.show()` from class.

Full code: https://gist.github.com/gitex/83b06e8ceaac18ad5dec2d332ed6cbaa

Comment: Hi JRazor, thanks a lot for helping out here... I added `print(window)` after your `window = Widget.getData()` but after writing something in the edit field and hitting the Apply button nothings happens... would you know what is wrong then?

Comment: Great it works! But when I tried to have more than one question in the same dialog box, the dialog opens twice. Any idea how to solve that? Please see my code in your [github](https://gist.github.com/gitex/83b06e8ceaac18ad5dec2d332ed6cbaa)

Comment: @chan: Read the PyQt documentation before using them. This will save you a lot of questions. I added to Gist second field.

Comment: don't use getData second time

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! In the end I used a list of answers out from the static method (I added the final solution in my section above).